# angular4 upload image and pass to server and save into database(express and mongoose, mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, mongoose

Is there anyone knows how to upload an image within Angular 4 environment, then sending this data to the backend as express server, and using mongoose to store into mongodb? if anyone knows, please post the answer. Thank

File input

```
{{imgfile.errors | json}}
<div class="alert alert-danger"
*ngIf="size >= 300000">
  <strong>
    Can't upload this image. check image size!!!
  </strong>
</div>
```

Script

```
onFileChange(event) {
let reader = new FileReader();
if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
  console.log(event.target.files)
  let file = event.target.files[0];enter code here
  this.size = file.size;
  console.log(file.size);
  if (file.size <= 300000) {
    this.picSize = true;
  }
  reader.onload = () => {
    this.new_food.image = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

}

Comment: I would break this up and try to tackle the pieces one at a time, as is this is a big ask on SO... I have a job someone do it for me ;)

Comment: thanks actually found a way to store that image into mongodb, but the data seems like a punch of mixed characters. and eventually, can retrieve it back to display. really want to find out if there is a better way

Comment: Would be good to show what work you've done so far.  I'm guessing you're base64 encoding the image and storing it in the DB.  In most cases I think it's usually good enough to upload the asset somewhere and then save a link to it (save the file by id and save the extension to restore the original extension when sending back to the client).  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Ultimately if storing the data for the file itself in the DB is a good idea depends on the use case or project but in most medium/big things I've seen people use S3 or the like for files.

Comment: Typically you don't want to query for the image data itself so putting the actual data in the database doesn't really make sense.  Also I'm some sort of angular "expert" but not an expert in mongoose etc. but without code to look at and more specific questions it is hard for anyone to answer this.

Comment: I have posted angularjs code please see them

Comment: I added what you posted as "answers" the the question.  Try to edit the question if you have privileges in general so people don't get confused thinking what's being posted are potential answers to the question.  The `readAsDataURL` function as explained here does a base64 encoding of the data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL it basically takes the binary data and converts it to base64, then it uses numbers+characters to represent those 64 base symbols since that can be easily transmitted then decoded/stored.

Comment: This is a fine way to encode the data for the sake of transmitting it but when it comes to storing it on the service side you can optionally decode the data and save it as a file (before saving the file can save an entry in a DB to get a new ID and use that ID to save the file)  This way you aren't bloating your database with image assets.

Answer (score 0):

```
  onFileChange(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      console.log(event.target.files)
      let file = event.target.files[0];enter code here
      this.size = file.size;
      console.log(file.size);
      if (file.size <= 300000) {
        this.picSize = true;
      }
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.new_food.image = reader.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }
```